# How could I write to a file a dynamic object using FileHelpers?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, dynamic, filehelpers

I'm actually pursuing a way to **create csv file which records could vary on type and order**. They are defined by the user on both ways and I'm actually handling their types safely.

I loved using FileHelpers library in order to read/write files on C# since it's fast, reliable and trustable, so I was wondering how could I perform this export operation using it, and reviewing questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013756/filehelpers-creating-a-field-object) the evil part comes when needing to populate the class with the desired values, so I could **write** the file. All the related questions are focusing on reading registries and I need to write them.

Am I right thinking that I might need to use `Reflection` so I could roam this new `type` and its properties or is there any way to "add a record" specifying the value while creating the fields?

This FileHelpers way was an option and of course the second one was doing this manually, but I was curious if there is an *easier* way.

```
var builder = new DelimitedClassBuilder("DynamicDocument", ";");
builder.AddField("Date", typeof(DateTime));
var dynamicType = builder.CreateRecordClass();
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the class builders is the best way to do this with FileHelpers.  You do need to keep a copy of the type that is created so it can be used by your generic classes.

Just remember, that you must do all the work before calling CreateRecordClass() as that then generates the type.

Here is a link to another S/O question with a whole bunch of code that shows how to do it: [FileHelpers.Dynamic.ClassBuilder.CreateRecordClass Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35361374/filehelpers-dynamic-classbuilder-createrecordclass-error)

Now, if you are working purely with properly formatted files, you can let FileHelpers do all that work for you as long as they are always properly delimited and you handle any type conversion based on the column name.